# multiple input form inside multiple input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Multiple input Form

[image]

```
<form method="post" action="input" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Name </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama_barang" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option value="2">pakaian</option>
              <option value="3">celana</option>
              <option value="4">Kemeja</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Stock </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="stok" placeholder="Stock">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div id="ListType">
            <div id="typerow2" class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Type Of Variant">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a id="typerow2" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove_type" style="color:white;">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div id="ListVariant2">
                        <div id="svariantrow4" class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="variant[]" placeholder="Variant Name">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <a id="svariantrow4" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove_variant" style="color:white;">Del</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="variant[]" placeholder="Variant Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a id="ListVariant2" class="btn btn-success btn_add_type" style="color:white;">Add</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="type[]" placeholder="Type Of Variant">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <a id="AddType" class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white;">Add Type</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div id="ListVariant"><div id="variantrow2" class="row"><div class="col"><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="text" name="variant[]" placeholder="Variant Name"></div></div><div class="col"><div class="form-group"><a id="variantrow2" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove_variant" style="color:white;">Del</a></div></div></div></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="variant[]" placeholder="Variant Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <a id="AddVariant" class="btn btn-success" style="color:white;">Add</a>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" width="400px" alt="Image Upload" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to process multiple input form inside multiple input so that the data is stored as below on laravel, i am using javascript for dynamic input form. I was wondering how to enter a mutiple input array with its sub. usually I will use the attribute 'name = "type []"' for massail input. then how to save the variation variable so that the input that comes in matches the type that has been entered

database-example

[image]

Comment: please write some code you tried to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your database that would meet your requirements, relating tables might help and you can easily fetch the data the way you want using queries there is also other way, you can use json field in (**MySQL**) based on your table design so you can store you so called array variants to your database but the downside of this is during comparing and relating the data because it will be a messed.